# Multiple rolling function calls in one pandas apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, moving-average, rolling-computation

I am calculating 5 different types of future cumulative returns using five different `.groupby.rolling.apply()` function calls. Each call takes a lot of time. Is it possible to combine all these functions calls in one so that it runs efficiently? Thanks in advance.

```py
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=1)
df['next_1'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO'], as_index=False).RET.shift(-1).rolling(indexer).progress_apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1)
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)
df['next_3'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO'], as_index=False).RET.shift(-1).rolling(indexer).progress_apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1)
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=6)
df['next_6'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO'], as_index=False).RET.shift(-1).rolling(indexer).progress_apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1)
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=12)
df['next_12'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO'], as_index=False).RET.shift(-1).rolling(indexer).progress_apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1)
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=60)
df['next_60'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO'], as_index=False).RET.shift(-1).rolling(indexer).progress_apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod() - 1)
```